# spyder, numpy, anaconda : cannot import name multiarray

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, spyder

I am on Windows 10, 64bits, use Anaconda 4 and I created an environment with python 2.7 (C:/Anaconda3/envs/python2/python.exe)
In this environment, I successfully installed numpy and when I type "python", enter, "import numpy", enter, it works perfectly in the anaconda prompt window.

In spyder however, when I open a python console and type "import numpy", I get "cannot import name multiarray". I have obviously changed the path of the python interpreter used by spyder to match the python.exe of the environment I created (C:/Anaconda3/envs/python2/python.exe). I also updated the PYTHONSTARTUP to C:/Anaconda3/envs/python2/Lib/site-packages/spyderlib/scientific_startup.py

It's supposed to be the exact same python program running but it's two different behavior. How is it possible and how to fix it ?

PS: I already tried the various solutions to this error like uninstalling numpy and reinstalling it. It shouldn't be a problem with numpy since it works just fine in the python console of the anaconda prompt window.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by executing the spyder version of the python2 environment.
It is located in Anaconda3\envs\python2\Scripts\spyder.exe

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered same issue. I have followed every possible solution, which is stated on stack-overflow. But no luck. The cause of error might be the python console. I have installed a 3.5 Anaconda, and the default console is the python 2.7, which I have installed primarily with pydev. I did this and now it is working absolutely fine. Go to tools>preferences and click on reset to defaults. It might solve the issue.  Or another solution is to uninstall the current Anaconda i.e. y.x and installing the correct one according to the default. In my case 2.7 Anaconda instead of 3.5